# How to turn on/off $log.debug in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, logging, angularjs-log

I'm trying to use $log.debug("Foo").  How can it be turned on off. I can't find a sample anywhere.  I think it need to be set in the config, but I cant seem to get that to work either.

Where does one set the on and off switch?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

`$logProvider.debugEnabled(true)`

This is only available in AngularJS 1.1.2 or later.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1625

Here is an example of it being set.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.config(function($logProvider){
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $log ) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.model = {value: "test"};
  $log.debug('TEST Log');
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HZCAoS?p=preview

By default it is on.

Comment: Where do you put the $logProvider.debugEnabled(true) ?

Comment: Thank you.  I was using an older version of angularjs.  I just overwrote the log provider in the angular.js file in my app.

Comment: @EricRohlfs - use the `config` block.

Comment: Now does `$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);` simply disable the `.debug()` method, leaving `.log(), .info(), etc` enabled?

Comment: What is the point then? I assume, that developers don't limit themselves with only `$log.debug`. Shouldn't there be an option in provider, that would allow to disable all `$log` service output. Or allow to specify what to leave. Now that would be usefull. Sure I could write my own service wrapper for `$log` service and handle it from there..somehow, but again what's the point in this option then?

Comment: @Eugene I agree with your thoughts; my guess is perhaps they figured developers *would* limit themselves to $log.debug for those messages that they only wanted to occur while in "debug/development"  mode on their project, and devs would only use the other $log types for cases in which they figured there was no real case for switching them off.  Like if you were creating a library, putting info, warning and error message logging code in that you saw no reason to suppress, as those messages are part of the logic contained in your library to help your users use it properly.

Comment: the `TEST Log ` never shows up. did something change? EDIT my bad, chrome "Verbose" was disabled

Answer (score 14):

You can override the default $log behavior with a decorator to enhace the log level. This is an example:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($logProvider, $provide){

    $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);

    $provide.decorator('$log', function ($delegate) {
        //Original methods
        var origInfo = $delegate.info;
        var origLog = $delegate.log;

        //Override the default behavior
        $delegate.info = function () {

            if ($logProvider.debugEnabled())
                origInfo.apply(null, arguments)
        };

        //Override the default behavior    
        $delegate.log = function () {

            if ($logProvider.debugEnabled())
                origLog.apply(null, arguments)
        };

        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

This was inspired from the work of John Crosby at http://www.thekuroko.com/using-angulars-log-provider/

Answer (score 13):

I have faced the same issue but it's not an issue to be solved by coding instead just enable it from browser console

Go to console of browser and set level to verbose

Comment: I had to do this to see `$log.debug` messages in Chrome.

Comment: Which by default is off.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Since the solution requires us to turn on `Verbose` flag, I think the best way to handle logging in angular would be to simply alter the native `console.log` function in Production Environment for the entire application.

```
angular.module("myModule")
.config(function(){
    //if production environment
    console.log = ()=>{};
})
```

That's it. In production environment, this should disable logging everywhere. Also there is no need to inject `$log` in every controller now.
Simply `console.log("logging message")` works!

You can also disable `console.info`, `console.warn`, `console.error` and `console.debug` the same way as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Diego's response but adding some env config and making it shorter.
You can simply run your app using: `NODE_ENV=development` or `NODE_ENV=production`

E.g.1. `NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server`

E.g.2. `NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

```
$logProvider.debugEnabled(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development');
$provide.decorator('$log', function($delegate) {
    $delegate.info = $logProvider.debugEnabled() ? $delegate.info : function() {};
    $delegate.log = $logProvider.debugEnabled() ? $delegate.log : function() {};
    return $delegate;
});
```