# Globally disabling $log.debug in Angular 1.4.2

Tags: angularjs, debugging, logging

I have an angular app that is logging debug messages in the console using $log.debug. The app is increasing in size, so I wanted to see if there was a way to globally disable these log files when deployed in production. I saw a few posts where you can configure the $logProvider to disable logging debugs to the console (*$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);*), but this does not work for me. Here is one of my controllers where I added this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('bodyShop')

        // This config was added to globally disable logs
        .config(function($logProvider){
            $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
        })

        .controller('CustomerController', function ($log, $window) {

         var vm = this;
         ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
```

This does not throw any errors and the page works as expected, but I can still see all the debug logs in the console.

Also, I know this will only "globally" disable logs in this controller. But I also tried to add the $logProvider config in my module so that I can disable logs across my entire app, but with no success.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: actually should disable across whole app. There will only be one `$logProvider` regardless of how many modules there are.  Are you sure that it's not enabled somewhere else in another config?

Comment: I have used Yeoman to generate an AngularJS-Gulp app. Any idea where  else this could be configured?

Comment: @charlietfl - It turns out it was located in a config file (index.config.js). Thanks! If you are willing to post that as an answer, I would be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `$logProvider` in an app regardless of how many modules so setting `debugEnabled` once would be global across all modules that are injected

The only explanation would be that it is being set somewhere else in another config that runs after the one shown

Comment: Thank you! Since my app was built using Yeoman angular-gulp generator, I found the configuration for $logProvider in index.config.js. I verified that it works by changing the value to false. Logging of all $log.debug was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator to override the default logging behaviour. There is an article by John Crosby at http://www.thekuroko.com/using-angulars-log-provider/

Here is some code that will do the job from answer [How to turn on/off $log.debug in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561853/how-to-turn-on-off-log-debug-in-angularjs) I haven't run it, but I think it's what you are looking for

```
angular.module('app').config(function($logProvider, $provide){

    $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);

    $provide.decorator('$log', function ($delegate) {
        //Original methods
        var origInfo = $delegate.info;
        var origLog = $delegate.log;

        //Override the default behavior
        $delegate.info = function () {

            if ($logProvider.debugEnabled())
                origInfo.apply(null, arguments)
        };

        //Override the default behavior    
        $delegate.log = function () {

            if ($logProvider.debugEnabled())
                origLog.apply(null, arguments)
        };

        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Comment: I will have to look into decorators. The above mentioned code did not work for me. But if the "$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);" does not work, then it seems I will have to go with this route